# Change point clouds IDs with respect to a relationship defined in an array

Tags: python, arrays, point-clouds, laspy

I'm a new user of Python.

I'm trying to change ID to points in a point cloud.
My point cloud has already a classification, so each point has got different IDs.
I have an array that relates these IDs to new ones, something like:

```
ID_relation [[1, 50], [2, 41], [3, 21], [4, 78], [5, 4]]
```

I can read IDs from the point cloud in this way:

`old_ID = myfile.intensity`

(with laspy)(in my file IDs are saved like intensity value, but it's not a problem).

I don't know how to change ID values with the array relationship.

Comment: I recommend storing the id relations in a python dictionary so they're easier to retrieve: `ID_relation_dict = dict([[1, 50], [2, 41], [3, 21], [4, 78], [5, 4]])`. This way, whenever you have an `old_id`, you can get the corresponding new_id immediately by writing `ID_relation_dict[old_id]`. As for your actual question, it's hard to understand what your problem is. You have a file or a data structure describing the point cloud, and you want to modify that file to change the IDs in it? What does the file or the data structure look like?

Comment: My input file is a LAS file, which can be read with laspy; And yes, my problem is to change the IDs (change all points with ID value '1' in ID value '50', and so on)

Comment: Any help? Please